# Volume mount not writing out to host machine

Tags: docker

I'm trying to set up my docker container with a host machine directory mounted to the container for writing logs out to.  My dockerfile is pretty simple:

```
FROM golang:1.9.2

WORKDIR /

COPY daemon /

CMD ["./daemon", "-d", "debug"]
```

Where `daemon` is the compiled binary of a Go program.  I'm starting the container via the following command:

```
docker run -d --restart unless-stopped -v /var/log/scope/:/var/log/scope/ slack_daemon
```

Where `slack_daemon` is the name of the image the above dockerfile is built into.

However, the directory `/var/log/scope` in the container is not being written out to the host machine.  Anything I place in that directory on the host machine is visible inside the container, but neither writing to existing files or creating new files in that directory in the container is writing out to the host machine.  No error is being thrown by docker or any of the commands, it just simply isn't writing anything out to the host directory.

Running Docker 17.09.0-ce-mac35, stable channel, on OSX 10.12.6.

Things I've tried:

- Running the `docker run` command as `sudo`.
- Adding the `--privileged` flag to `docker run`.
- `chmod 777` on `/var/log/scope` on the host machine.

I specifically need that directory in both host and container, as our code and log handler both expect that location and it would be too large of a change for this current issue to alter that.

Any guidance on this would be appreciated.  Most of the sources online that I can find suggest that this is an SELinux issue, but I'm not getting the "permission denied" error, and this is OSX, not linux.

I've also checked on the `/var` dir itself.  It aliases to `/private/var`:

```
lrwxr-xr-x@   1 root       wheel     11 Oct 30 10:54:11 2017 var -> private/var
```

And `/private` is by default a shared directory within the file sharing settings in docker.

Comment: Docker for Mac runs in a Linux VM. The OSX host directory becomes an [`osxfs`](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs/) file system in the VM that can then be mounted into a container.  Do bind mounts from osx generally work on your machine?

Comment: `echo atest > ~/test` - `docker run --rm -v ~/test:/test busybox sh -c 'echo btest > /test'` - `cat ~/test`

Comment: > Do bind mounts from osx generally work on your machine?  No idea, first I've tried them.  I'll test that script when I get to work tomorrow and report back.

Comment: Ok, that worked as expected (output was `btest`).  So it's some permission issue with `/var/log/scope`.  But that directory is set to `777` mode, which is what baffles me.

Comment: Further mystery, it appears to actually be writing the files out *somewhere*.  Started a new base ubuntu container to test overall mounting, and the files I `touch`ed in the other container are present in the proper directory.  I just don't know where they are being written out to the host machine.